# Convert an expression from one form to another

Tags: simplifying-expressions, expression-manipulation

I have this expression

```
-0.433284-0.758719 x+0.00289158 x^2-0.443672 y+0.00149027 y^2
```

I want to express it in terms of $$\frac{(x-h)^2}{b^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{a^2}$$. Using Solve gave me a big mess:

```
Solve[-0.433284-0.758719 xP+0.00289158 xP^2-0.443672 yP+0.00149027 yP^2==(xP-h)^2/b^2+(yP-k)^2/a^2,{a,b,h,k}]
```

[image: Solve]

What can I do to get it in the form I wanted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems. One is that you want `SolveAlways` to find values for the parameters for which the expressions are equivalent. The second is that, as stated, it's not possible because the system is overdetermined. You'll want to allow for a constant term in your second expression.

```
expr1 = -0.433284 - 0.758719 x + 0.00289158 x^2 - 0.443672 y + 
   0.00149027 y^2;
expr2 = (x - h)^2/b^2 + (y - k)^2/a^2 - c;
```

Now we find the parameter sets that work.

```
solns = SolveAlways[expr1 == expr2, {x, y}];
viable = Select[solns, 
   FreeQ[{a, b, c, h, k} /. #, a | b | c | h | k] &];

(* Out[337]= {-83.2248525772 + 0.00289158 (-131.194537243 + x)^2 + 
  0.00149027 (-148.856247526 + y)^2, -83.2248525772 + 
  0.00289158 (-131.194537243 + x)^2 + 
  0.00149027 (-148.856247526 + y)^2, -83.2248525772 + 
  0.00289158 (-131.194537243 + x)^2 + 
  0.00149027 (-148.856247526 + y)^2, -83.2248525772 + 
  0.00289158 (-131.194537243 + x)^2 + 
  0.00149027 (-148.856247526 + y)^2} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

This particular problem can dealt with algebraically by completing squares, equating coefficients and subtracting constants. (I am making the assumptions this is a left hand side whose right hand side is 0).

```
pol = -0.433284 - 0.758719 x + 0.00289158 x^2 - 0.443672 y + 
   0.00149027 y^2;
cr = CoefficientRules[pol, {x, y}]
{p, q, r, s, t} = cr[[All, 2]];
{h, k} = 0.5 {-q/p, -s/r}
cons = p h^2 + r k^2
```

This yields for {h,k}:=

```
{131.195, 148.856}
```

The rearranged polynomial:

```
trp[x_, y_] := p (x - h)^2 + r (y - k)^2 - cons + t
```

[image]

and note:

```
Expand[trp[x, y]] == pol
```

yields `True`.

If the aim is to get to $\frac{(x-h)^2}{a^2}+\frac{(y-k)^2}{b^2}=1$

```
{a, b} = Sqrt[
  1/Coefficient[(trp[x + h, y + k] + cons - t)/(cons - t), {x^2, 
     y^2}]]
```

This yields:

```
{169.652, 236.316}
```

The boolean is hampered by numericals but to show the rearrangement is equivalent:

```
stf[x_, y_] := (x - h)^2/a^2 + (y - k)^2/b^2 - 1

Column[{TraditionalForm[pol], 
  TraditionalForm[Expand[(cons - t) stf[x, y]]]}]
```

[image]

Putting it all together:

```
TraditionalForm[
 StringForm[
  "\!\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\((x - `1`)\), \(2\)], \
SuperscriptBox[\(`2`\), \
\(2\)]]\)+\!\(\*FractionBox[SuperscriptBox[\((y - `3`)\), \(2\)], \
SuperscriptBox[\(`4`\), \(2\)]]\)=1", h, a, k, b]]
```

[image]

Visualizing:

```
Grid[{{TraditionalForm[pol == 0], 
   TraditionalForm[stf[x, y] == 0]}, {ContourPlot[
    pol == 0, {x, -500, 500}, {y, -500, 500}, ImageSize -> 300],
   ContourPlot[stf[x, y] == 0, {x, -500, 500}, {y, -500, 500}, 
    ImageSize -> 300]}}, Frame -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for this. I will look into your answer in more detail tomorrow since I'm studying for a test but it seems a very intuitive way to solve this problem at first glance. Also thank you for using CoefficientRules since I've been using very clunky ways to separate coefficients as seen in this Q&A (http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51654/an-easier-way-to-find-the-properties-of-an-ellipse-from-its-equation). I hope you could help me over there as well as it seems like an extension of this question.