# Extracting the major and minor axes values from the elliptic equation

Tags: list-manipulation, calculus-and-analysis

If the equation of ellipse is:

$$\frac{x^2}{a^2}+\frac{y^2}{b^2}=1,$$

then how can the major and minor axes values in the denominators be extracted from `eq`?

```
eq = x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1;
```

> a^2=4; a=2; b^2=3; b=sqrt(3)

Comment: A more general problem is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51654/1871

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Expressing the ellipse as `eq == 0`:

```
eq = x^2/4 + y^2/3 - 1;
```

The semi-major axes are calculated from the eigenvalues of the second derivatives of `eq`:

```
1/Sqrt[Eigenvalues[D[eq, {{x, y}, 2}]/2]] // NumericalSort
(*    {Sqrt[3], 2}    *)
```

This is more general than pattern-matching approaches and also works on rotated ellipses:

```
eq = x^2/4 + x y/7 + y^2/3 - 1;
1/Sqrt[Eigenvalues[D[eq, {{x, y}, 2}]/2]] // NumericalSort
(*    {2 Sqrt[42/(49 + Sqrt[193])], 2 Sqrt[42/(49 - Sqrt[193])]}    *)
```

Answer (score 5):

```
eq1 = x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1;
eq2 = x^2/a^2 + y^2/b^2 == 1;
Solve[Denominator[Flatten@(List @@@ List @@ eq1)] == 
  Denominator[Flatten@(List @@@ List @@ eq2)], 
 Assumptions -> {a > 0 && b > 0}]
```

> `{{a -> 2, b -> Sqrt[3]}}`

Answer (score 5):

Another possibility is  (*8 more left to do *)

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq = x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1;
normalized = First[eq] - Last[eq]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Coefficient[normalized, x^Exponent[normalized, x]];
Sqrt[Denominator[%]]  (*a*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
Coefficient[normalized, y^Exponent[normalized, y]];
Sqrt[Denominator[%]]  (*b*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

---

If the exponent is not meant to be the max but only `2` then do

```
ClearAll["Global`*"]
eq = x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1;
normalized = First[eq] - Last[eq]
Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, x^2]]] (*a*)
Sqrt[Denominator[Coefficient[normalized, y^2]]] (*b*)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

```
eq = x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1;
TreeForm[eq]
```

[image]

To extract the coefficients:

```
(1/Sqrt[#]) &@(First /@ Level[eq, {2}])
```

> {2, Sqrt[3]}

Answer (score 4):

try https://resources.wolframcloud.com/FunctionRepository/resources/EllipseProperties

```
ass = ResourceFunction["EllipseProperties"][x^2/4 + y^2/3 == 1, {x, y}];
ass["SemimajorAxisLength"]
ass["SemiminorAxisLength"]
```

> 2
>
> Sqrt[3]

[image]